# Threaded application sleeps with other application

Tags: pthreads

I have a weird problem with my threaded software.

I start 2 instances of the software. Each instance has 2 threads, one thread creates a socket to use, and the other one is uses the socket for communication.

When one of the threads in one instance calls `sleep(3)`, the other threads in the the other instance sleeps too. And the weirdest thing is that when I rebooted the computer, it works the first time, but after trying a second time, it sleeps like described.

How is this possible? Is it using some shared resource?

Comment: For a moment there the question title made me think you were asking about an threaded application who were sleeping around with "other" application ;-p

Answer (score 2):

Sleep suspends your *process*, not your thread. See [sleep vs pthead_yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936993/pthread-what-is-the-difference-between-time-hsleep-and-pthread-hpthread-y) for more details.

Comment: But even so, why is it sleeping the other instance because they are different processes?

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread the question. You'll need to give more details. Preferably a SSCCE (http://sscce.org).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried wrapping your sleep function in a prophylactic?